# Searching in a unsorted tree recursively

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I'm trying to search an element e in the tree, however as you can see my search(Position,E) doesn't return a Position. However when I add "return null;" at the end of method. It only works when the Position I'm looking for is at the left most children of its parent and it returns null otherwise. How can I keep it working until it reaches to the end of tree?

```
public Position<E> search(E e) {
    return search(root(), e);
}

public Position<E> search(Position<E> p, E e) {
    if(p.getElement().equals(e))
        return p;
    for(Position<E> c: children(p))
            return search(c, e);
}
```

Comment: what does **childeren(p)** return ?

Comment: Does your Position have a leftNode and rightNode? Is the tree a binary tree? or n-ary?

Comment: @Alp children(p) returns an Iterable<Position<E>> which are the children of node p,

Comment: @pedromss it's a general tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is in this loop:

```
for(Position<E> c: children(p))
        return search(c, e);
```

Imagine that the element you're searching for is in the second child of the node rather than the first. With the above code, on the first iteration of the loop, you'll recursively explore the first child, which returns false, then immediately return false without having had the chance to explore the second child. In other words, your method only looks at the very first child, so it might not find what you're looking for.

To fix this, try rewriting the code like this:

```
if(p.getElement().equals(e))
    return p;

for(Position<E> c: children(p)) {
    Position<E> result = search(c, e);
    if (result != null) return result;
}
return null;
```

This makes the recursive call in each subtree. If any one call fails to find the element, that's fine - you just continue to the next. If any one call does find the element, you return it. If none of the calls find the element, then you return null to indicate failure.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of each subtree and it's return value. Try something like the following:

```
public Position<E> search(E e) {
    return search(root(), e);
}

public Position<E> search(Position<E> p, E e) {
    if(p.getElement().equals(e)) {
        return p;
    }
    for(Position<E> c: children(p)) {
        Position tmp = search(c, e);
        if (tmp != null) {
            return tmp;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thank you,

Yuri